# Toc doesn't linebreak within include

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I'm writing a handbook.
I can call for a Table of Contents and it works fine (with the option of having "chapter" written in front of number and Title), but as soon as I go to `\include` out of the input folder, it stops doing line breaks. How do I need to alter my code?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
    \titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
      [0pt]% <left>
      {}% <above-code>
      {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
      {}% <numberless-entry-format>
      {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % never indent first line

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
%Table of Content
\doublespacing
\tableofcontents
\onehalfspacing
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Foreword}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Why join?}

\include{input/test}

\chapter{Breaks here}

\end{document}
```

with "test" being simply

```
\chapter{Doesn't break without section}
dsfds
%\section{See}
```

Example where it doesn't work (Test file without section)
[image: Test file without section]

Example where it does work (Test file with section)
[image: Test file with section]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\include` has nothing to do with the problem. Use `\titlecontents`, not `titlecontents*`. The latter is specifically to avoid line breaks between entries.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc

\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {\bfseries}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Breaks here}

\end{document}
```

[image]